# web service calling error of argument exception in window phone 7

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7

I am doing calling an asmx web service for window phone. Here is the code I have. When I execute this code, it gives me the error of:

> ArgumentException: Invalid appId
>   Parameter name: appId : ID=3010.V2_Soap.Translate.3C775314

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.LanguageServiceClient myclient = new ServiceReference1.LanguageServiceClient();

        myclient.TranslateAsync(AppIdString, textBox1.Text, "en", "fr", "text/plain", "general");

        myclient.TranslateCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.TranslateCompletedEventArgs>(translatecompleted);

    }

    private void translatecompleted(object obj, ServiceReference1.TranslateCompletedEventArgs e)
    { 

        textBlock1.Text = e.Result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I removed your first parameter because if that's your AppID, then it's best to keep it private. If it's not an AppID, or you're happy for it to be public, you can add it back. (not that it makes a difference now)

Comment: Actually i took this syntax to check either web service is working or not. How can i get app id unless i submitted my app to market?

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't tried it. The string looked like it was an ID  of sorts so I wasn't sure if it was private. If you're using the MS Translator API this might be helpful but I'm not familiar with the process http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx If you're using the Hawaii project then it seems you can register for an Application ID http://igrali.com/2011/12/20/windows-phone-and-microsoft-research-hawaii/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem. the error was that i am not putting servicesoapclient in it. Here is the code which is correct.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        jomarzi.ServiceSoapClient obj = new jomarzi.ServiceSoapClient();
        obj.HelloWorldCompleted +=new EventHandler<jomarzi.HelloWorldCompletedEventArgs>(obj_HelloWorldCompleted);
        obj.HelloWorldAsync();



    }

    private void obj_HelloWorldCompleted(object sender, jomarzi.HelloWorldCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBlock1.Text = e.Result;
    }
```